# Elasticsearch update by query - update only document with minimum timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to the elasticsearch and I am trying to get the first document from my index and update its list of object.

I tried several queries e.g:

```
POST localhost:9200/test-index/_update_by_query

{
 "size":1,
 "sort": [{"timestamp":"asc"}],
  "script": {
      "inline": "ctx._source.addresses.add(params.address)",
        "params" : {
           "address" :{
                  "street": "Yemen Road",
                  "number": 15,
                  "county": "Yemen"
              }
        }
    }
}
```

But this updates all my documents.
What is the fastest way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you try until now? I would suggest adding `query` key also, like `"query": { "match_all": { } }`. Also I think it should sort descending.

Comment: You are right, the order should be desc, that’s an oversight. 
I tried with the query+match_all, but it didn’t work.. it probably applies the script before applying the size.

Comment: I got the answer on the https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-update-by-query-update-only-the-last-document/278506 . this can only be done with 2 api calls.

Comment: Great, you should post the answer here and accept it so people can find the solution easier.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following answer from the elasticsearch community:

Update by query does not support a size. You would need to run a query first using size and sorting, and then use the update API on that single document.